# How to specify join types in AWS Glue?

Tags: pyspark, etl, aws-glue

I am using AWS Glue to join two tables. By default, it performs `INNER JOIN`. I want to do a `LEFT OUTER JOIN`. I referred the AWS Glue documentation but there is no way to pass the join type to the `Join.apply()` method. Is there a way to achieve this in AWS Glue?

```
## @type: Join
## @args: [keys1 = id, keys2 = "user_id"]
## @return: cUser
## @inputs: [frame1 = cUser0, frame2 = cUserLogins]
#cUser = Join.apply(frame1 = cUser0, frame2 = +, keys1 = "id", keys2 = "user_id", transformation_ctx = "<transformation_ctx>")


## @type: Join
## @args: [keys1 = id, keys2 = user_id]
## @return: datasource0
## @inputs: [frame1 = cUser, frame2 = cKKR]
datasource0 = Join.apply(frame1 = cUser0, frame2 = cKKR, keys1 = "id", keys2 = "user_id", transformation_ctx = "<transformation_ctx>")

## @type: Join
## @args: [keys1 = branch_id, keys2 = user_id]
## @return: datasource1
## @inputs: [frame1 = datasource0, frame2 = cBranch]
datasource1 = Join.apply(frame1 = datasource0, frame2 = cBranch, keys1 = "branch_id", keys2 = "user_id", transformation_ctx = "<transformation_ctx>")
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Currently, LEFT and RIGHT joins are not supported by AWS Glue. But, we can still achieve it by converting the DynamicFrame to the DataFrame and using join method.

Here the example:

```
cUser0 = glueContext.create_dynamic_frame.from_catalog(database = "captains", table_name = "cp_txn_winds_karyakarta_users", transformation_ctx = "cUser")

cUser0DF = cUser0.toDF()

cKKR = glueContext.create_dynamic_frame.from_catalog(database = "captains", table_name = "cp_txn_winds_karyakarta_karyakartas", redshift_tmp_dir = args["TempDir"], transformation_ctx = "cKKR")

cKKRDF = cKKR.toDF()

dataSource0 = cUser0DF.join(cKKRDF, cUser0DF.id == cKKRDF.user_id,how='left_outer')
```

Comment: @Vikash , how can we join two tables with selected fields only as my main table had more than 1000 fields?

Comment: Have you tried SelectFields transformation on the dynamic frame?

Comment: Did not know about this as I am new to Glue, do have any sample code to which I can refer. Below is the query which I am trying to run through Glue.

Comment: SELECT v.col1, v.col2 , s.col3
FROM 
(SELECT col1,col2  FROM t1  WHERE col1 > 0 ) v
LEFT JOIN 
(SELECT col1, col3 FROM t2 WHERE col1  > 0  GROUP  BY  col1) s
ON v.col1 = s.col1

Answer (score 0):

If you import DynamicFrames `from awsglue.dynamicframe import DynamicFrame`,
you can then do

```
dataSource2 = DynamicFrame.fromDF(datasource0.join(datasource1, (datasource0['user_id'] == datasource1['user_id']), "left"), glueContext, "dataSource2")
```